# show and hide blocks while changing in dropdown [Rails4, jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which contains a dropdown of 3 values QUESTIONS_TYPES = {'single', 'multiple', A text}

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question_type %><br>
    <%= f.select :question_type, Question::QUESTIONS_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a question type' %>
  </div>
```

Using Jquery, this dropdown shows other fields(in the block whose class is .answers_list) depending of the choosing value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#question_question_type').change(function(){
    var qst_type = $('#question_question_type option:selected').text()
      if (qst_type == 'Multiple' || qst_type == 'Single'){
          $('.answers_list').show();
      } else{
          $('.answers_list').hide();
      }
  });
});
```

The thing is when I access to the form via a link:

```
<%= link_to 'New Question', new_question_path %>
```

My dropdown doesn't respond the jQuery action, once i refresh the page it does. Any suggestion?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try adding this event without on ready event? I mean try it this way
$('#question_question_type').change(function(){
    var qst_type = $('#question_question_type option:selected').text()
      if (qst_type == 'Multiple' || qst_type == 'Single'){
          $('.answers_list').show();
      } else{
          $('.answers_list').hide();
      }
  });

Comment: Doing this it dons't work in both cases. being a jquery I think it is necesary to be ready to any event calling in the page.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$( ".target" ).toggle();
```

see
[Click here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: using toggle my block will be hiding while choosing 'Multiple' or 'Single' as well. My problem is the event is not responding till I refresh the page.